# PHPStorm 8 version control (git) scope to ignore files in PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: php, git, magento, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I would only like to run an inspection ([phpcs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)) on files that are not ignored by git as the core code of Magento (which is ignored) does not really have code style so the inspector goes wild.

So I see in Settings | [Scopes](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/scopes.html) you need to match as a pattern, is it possible to define the .gitignore files somehow.

I think this is not possible, so any other solutions of keeping files out of [PHPCodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to add such ignored files/patterns into a scope manually -- they will not be magically read from `.gitignore` (or any other similar file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure JetBrains product integration with phpcs. Integration will bring you even more flexibility.

Please check documentation http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html